# H5PY/Numpy - Setting the inner shape of a numpy arrays (for h5py)

Tags: python, numpy, h5py

I am trying to use h5py to store data as a list of tuples of (images, angles). Images are numpy arrays of size (240,320,3) of type uint8 from OpenCV while angles are just a number of type float16.

When using h5py, you need to have a predetermine shape in order to maintain a usable speed of read/write. H5py preloads the entire dataset with arbitrary values in which you can index later and set these values to whatever you would like.

I would like to know how to set the shape of an inner numpy array when initializing the shape of a dataset for h5py. I believe the same solution would apply for numpy as well.

```
import h5py
import numpy as np

dset_length = 100

# fake data of same shape
images = np.ones((dset_length,240,320,3), dtype='uint8') * 255

# fake data of same shape
angles = np.ones(dset_length, dtype='float16') * 90
f = h5py.File('dataset.h5', 'a')
dset = f.create_dataset('dset1', shape=(dset_length,2))

for i in range(dset_length):
    # does not work since the shape of dset[0][0] is a number, 
    # and can't store an array datatype
    dset[i] = np.array((images[i],angles[i]))
```

Recreateing the problem in numpy looks like this:

```
import numpy as np 

a = np.array([ 
           [np.array([0,0]), 0], 
           [np.array([0,0]), 0], 
           [np.array([0,0]), 0]
         ])

a.shape # (3, 2)

b = np.empty((3,2))

b.shape # (3, 2)

a[0][0] = np.array([1,1])

b[0][0] = np.array([1,1]) # ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.
```

Comment: `b = np.empty((3,2), dtype=object)` will make it behave like `a`. But that's not really how you want it to behave anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `dtype` that `@Eric` creates should work with both `numpy` and `h5py`.  But I wonder if you really want or need that.  An alternative is to have two arrays in `numpy`, `images` and `angles`, one being 4d `uint8`, the other float.  In `h5py` you could create a `group`, and store these 2 arrays as `datasets`.

You could select the values for the `ith'` image with

```
 images[i,...], angles[i]     # or
 data[i]['image'], data[i]['angle']
```

for example:

```
import h5py
dt = np.dtype([('angle', np.float16), ('image', np.uint8, (40,20,3))])
data = np.ones((3,), dt)

f = h5py.File('test.h5','w')
g = f.create_group('data')
```

dataset with the compound dtype:

```
g.create_dataset('data', (3,), dtype=dt)
g['data'][:] = data
```

or datasets with the two arrays

```
g.create_dataset('image', (3,40,20,3), dtype=np.uint8)
g.create_dataset('angle', (3,), dtype=np.float16)
g['image'][:] = data['image']
g['angle'][:] = data['angle']
```

fetch angle array from either dataset:

```
g['data']['angle'][:]
g['angle'][:]
```

Answer (score 2):

In numpy, you can store that data with structured arrays:

```
dtype = np.dtype([('angle', np.float16), ('image', np.uint8, (240,320,3))])
data = np empty(10, dtype=dtype)
data[0]['angle'] = ... # etc
```